# Grails 2.1.1 - Unit testing and Mocking the elements of domain class

Tags: unit-testing, grails, grails-2.0

I need a little help in writing Unit tests for my project.
I have created Unit test classes for my Controllers and Domain.

**My Question is**-
I have a domain class named employee
It has-
    String id
    String firstname
    String middleInitial
    String lastname
    String status
    String empType
    String userid

And I want to mock them in my setUp() method under test class EmployeeControllerTest()

### I have added following Mixin

```
package EmployeeController

import static org.junit.Assert.*

import grails.test.mixin.*
import grails.test.mixin.support.*
import org.junit.*
import java.io.Serializable

import grails.test.mixin.TestFor
import grails.test.mixin.TestMixin
import grails.test.mixin.Mock
import grails.test.mixin.support.GrailsUnitTestMixin
import grails.test.mixin.domain.DomainClassUnitTestMixin
import grails.test.mixin.services.ServiceUnitTestMixin
import grails.test.mixin.web.ControllerUnitTestMixin
import grails.test.mixin.web.FiltersUnitTestMixin
import grails.test.mixin.web.GroovyPageUnitTestMixin
import grails.test.mixin.web.UrlMappingsUnitTestMixin
import grails.test.mixin.webflow.WebFlowUnitTestMixin

@TestMixin(GrailsUnitTestMixin)
@TestFor(EmployeeController)
@Mock([Employee])

class EmployeeControllerTests {

    void setUp() {
        // Setup logic here

       def Employee ce = new Employee()
       ce.put(empNo: "001", firstname: "amy", middleInitial: "ratr", lastname: "suz", status: "A", empType: "vendor", userid: "amar")
    }

    void tearDown() {
        // Tear down logic here
    }

    void testSomething() {
        //fail "Implement me"
    }
```

---

Kindly, let me know if I am missing something or need to do some modifications.

Thanks in Advance :)
Amy

Answer (score 4):

you shouldn't use `@TestMixin` together with `@TestFor` because TestMixin comes from the old unit testing stuff from grails 1.3 - I suggest removing it

Comment: Thanks - I have removed it from my domain test class and controller test classes...

Answer (score 1):

Your Unit Test case can be reduced to few lines of code:

```
package EmployeeController
import org.junit.*

import grails.test.mixin.TestFor
import grails.test.mixin.Mock

@TestFor(EmployeeController)
@Mock(Employee)
class EmployeeControllerTests {
    void setUp() {
       def ce =   
                new Employee(empNo: "001", firstname: "amy", 
                             middleInitial: "ratr", lastname: "suz", 
                             status: "A", empType: "vendor", 
                             userid: "amar").save(flush: true)
    }
}
```

`@TestFor` mixin takes care of the contoller mocking. You can very well access some keywords here like `controller`, `contoller.params`, `controller.request`, `controller.response` without instantiating controller.

`@Mock` is responsible for mocking the domain class `Employee`.

Comment: It says compilation error:      
| Compiling 14 source files.
| Error Compilation error compiling [unit] tests: startup failed:
C:\Users\amar\Documents\NetBeansProjects\File\test\unit\EmployeeControllerTests.groovy: 39: unable to resolve class Employee 
 @ line 39, column 17.
          def ce = new Employee(empNo: "001", firstname: "amy", ....
                   ^
                   

1 error

Comment: Yes because `Employee` is not imported. When I said few lines of code, I did not mean I can skip the import statements. :)

Comment: Apology for that, actually I am new to grails... I am working on it. I appreciate your help, I'll get back soon :)

Comment: Hi, I am able to proceed with it. I have all classes including - Domain, Controller, UnitTests under common package as "File". I have changed it and it is working now.

Comment: I am having all classes under same package, now it is working. But it is possible we can divide them into separate for each domain class, controller class and service class also test classes. Will it be right approach?

Comment: There are number of sample grails application in [Github](https://github.com/grails-samples). You can refer them to see how package structure is maintained in Grails applications. I would suggest to start with a simplistic sample like [petclinic](https://github.com/grails-samples/grails-petclinic). Also go through the Grails docs to see how [Convention over Configuration](http://grails.org/doc/2.2.1/guide/gettingStarted.html#conventionOverConfiguration) works.

Comment: Thanks, dmahapatro    I appreciate your help.

Comment: @Amy Glad I was helpful. Feel free to accept an appropriate answer to your question. This way it will help others visiting your question.